# Position imageButtons near a certain image

Tags: android, position, imagebutton

I have a problem with the positioning of ImageButtons near a certain image due to quite a lot of  device screen sizes. That is possible to position everything for 1 or 2 screen sizes but no more because it becomes to locate in the wrong place. I have looked for any solution for this issue and found that it is possible to optimaze all images`distances programmatically but a lot of programmmatical properties require 11 API for it. My app should work with 2.2, 2.3 versions too. Another solution is the creating of layout qualifiers but there is some screen sizes where my imageButtons position a bit wrongly and this way demand to create a lot of files, folders. Could you recommend me something interesting in this issue? Something what is more optimal and doesn`t eat device performance too much. I try to realize this picture http://s018.radikal.ru/i507/1209/07/e3f1024a5780.jpg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rlInjury"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:padding="10dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imMonkey"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:scaleX="0.8"
    android:scaleY="0.8"
    android:src="@drawable/monkey" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/pointer1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/pointer3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/pointer2" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/pointer2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In My opinion you should create layout (xml) file for each screen size devices like  layout-small,layout-large,layout-medium.I think there is not such a method.

Comment: I have tried it, for example, if I will make template for layout-normal which screen size varies from ~ 3-4 inchs then all ImageButtons will be in the wrong place almost each time when you will increase inch step, i.e. from 3.2inch to 3.3 inch and you will see another view. May be, I attach my View elemnts wrongly that is why it is so. I will attach a piece of my code. Could you recommend me what will be better to view it everywhere as correctly as it only possible.

Comment: Then use relative layout & take a refrence with each view where u want to place your button like  layout_below,layout_left,without it is is not possible

Comment: I know this properies of relative layout, however how is possible to reference it if human picture on the full screen and thee properies can align my elements by horizontal,vertical, to different corners and that`s all almost. That is to say i can use these properties with margin/padding to locate it exatly to that point of human part which is necessary. However, as I said I will use margin/padding with static value which willnot be changed depends on screen size.That`s a problem, I find only one good solution - scale or change margins of some elements depends on screen size programally.

Comment: However, to do it I need use 11 API or better for my app, that`s bad. Or, may be, is it possible to do for earlier versions too? I just try to find something with it and no result was received on the issue.

Comment: Could someone take me the mayor idea about how to solve this issue? Creation of different layouts will be to much using static padding for positioning elements near main picture for each screen size(more than 10 sizes). Programatically can be solved using 11API for 3.0 platform. How to solve it for 2.3-2.3.3 platform too in this case? May be, someone can present an example of how to od it?